# enterprise architect change sequence diagrams message text size

Tags: enterprise-architect, sequence-diagram, text-size

When I have sequence diagram in enterprise architect and I change the text size marking everything with Crtl + A and the rightclicking and using appearance -> set font and changing the text size it only changes it in the class names.
How can I change the text size of the messages so they are readable in a document?

Comment: Tough question, I failed to find the answer myself. There is no such setting also in "Tools > Options > Diagram > Sequence" and no simple answer in the help file. You can ask the Sparx Systems support and post the [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) here

Comment: You should chip in with a feature request. Sparx is very resilient when it comes to such requests. But many bugs can chop a tree too.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Geert, I don't think it can be done either.

You can make certain changes to a connector **label** by right-clicking it. These changes include boldness and font color, but not font size or typeface.

The corresponding information is stored as a set of key/value pairs in the PDATA5 column of the t_connector table in the EA database (not the t_diagramlinks table where you'd normally expect visual information to go).

In this string, whose interpretation is not documented in the help file, you'll find `BLD=1;` etc, but nothing that looks like it refers to font size or typeface. Which means you can't change it by scripting either.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't.
When I face that problem I copy the whole image of the diagram and cut it up in readable pieces before I put it into a document.
Yes, manually :/

Comment: that sucks. What worth is such a programm if it does not need the simple need of scaling it to fit a page and be readable :/

Comment: @Ginbak Scaling *is* supported. Right click somewhere on the diagram, choose Properties|Diagram|Advanced and there you can choose to fit on one page, or define the number of pages (horizontal and vertical) it has to scale to.

Comment: I do need that but what does it help me? I need it on one page and so I scaled it but I need to have readable text even on ONE page... so just scaling it to a page does not help the readability.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the font for ALL text, by **Tools | Options | Diagram | Appearance | Configure Default Element Fonts**

Comment: I am aware of that but I want to change the size in a single diagram. It works with the "set font" feature for the classes but not for the message texts which is ... not really clever...
when I change the text size for ALL the diagrams it destroys the positioning of my other diagrams, this is what bugs me :/